# RealityKit – How to set a ModelEntity's transparency?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, realitykit, reality-composer

In SceneKit, there are lots of options such as

- Use alpha channel of UIColor via `SCNMaterial.(diffuse|emission|ambient|...).contents`
- Use `SCNMaterial.transparency` (a CGFloat from 0.0 to 1.0)
- Use `SCNMaterial.transparent` (another SCNMaterialProperty)
- Use `SCNNode.opacity` (a CGFloat from 0.0 (fully transparent) to 1.0
  (fully opaque))

I wonder if there is a way to set transparency/opacity/alpha for ModelEntity in RealityKit?

Answer (score 14):

#### `RealityKit 1.0` (iOS | macOS)

There's one solution in RealityKit 1.0 allowing you to control object's transparency. You can do it using `baseColor` or `tintColor` instance properties of `SimpleMaterial()`:

```
 var tintColor: NSColor { get set }
 var baseColor: NSColor { get set }

 var tintColor: UIColor { get set }
 var baseColor: UIColor { get set }
```

It perfectly works in iOS even with color parameter:

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        arView.backgroundColor = .black

        var material = SimpleMaterial()

        material.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 1.0, 
                                        green: 1.0, 
                                         blue: 1.0, 
                                        alpha: 0.025)

        material.baseColor = MaterialColorParameter.color(UIColor.red)

        let mesh: MeshResource = .generateSphere(radius: 0.7)
        let modelEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh,
                                 materials: [material])
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        anchor.addChild(modelEntity)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}
```

[image]

#### macOS solution (texture example for RealityKit 1.0):

```
var material = SimpleMaterial()
         
// CYAN TINT and SEMI-TRANSPARENT ALPHA   
material.tintColor = NSColor.init(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)

material.baseColor = try! MaterialColorParameter.texture(TextureResource.load(contentsOf: url))
material.roughness = MaterialScalarParameter(floatLiteral: 0.0)
material.metallic = MaterialScalarParameter(floatLiteral: 1.0)
    
// CUBE WAS MADE IN REALITY COMPOSER
cubeComponent.materials = [material]
    
// SPHERE IS MADE PROGRAMMATICALLY
let mesh: MeshResource = .generateSphere(radius: 0.7)

let sphereComponent = ModelComponent(mesh: mesh,
                                materials: [material])

anchor.steelBox!.components.set(cubeComponent)
anchor.components.set(sphereComponent)
arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
```

Or if you do not need any texture on a model (just the color with opacity), you can control transparency via `baseColor` instance property:

```
material.baseColor = MaterialColorParameter.color(.init(red: 0.0,
                                                      green: 1.0, 
                                                       blue: 1.0, 
                                                      alpha: 0.5))
```

> If your scene contains both types of objects – that made in Reality Composer and made programmatically in Xcode and you assign the same material to both objects – a compiled app is presenting some rendering artefacts (look at the picture below).

[image]

> It's due to unstable work of RealityKit (because framework is too young at the moment). I think that in next version of RealityKit such bugs as `missing texture on Reality Composer model` and `weird reflection left from sphere` will be eliminated.

#### `RealityKit 2.0` (iOS | macOS)

In RealityKit 2.0 engineers of AR team gave us a `.color` property instead of `.baseColor` and `.tintColor`. These two mentioned are deprecated in iOS 15.

#### iOS solution (color example for RealityKit 2.0)

```
var material = SimpleMaterial()

material.color =  .init(tint: .red.withAlphaComponent(0.05), texture: nil)

material.baseColor       // deprecated in iOS 15
material.tintColor       // deprecated in iOS 15
```

[image]

#### iOS solution (texture example for RealityKit 2.0)

Texture can be applied using the same initializer:

```
material.color = try! .init(tint: .white.withAlphaComponent(0.9999),
                         texture: .init(.load(named: "mat.png", in: nil)))
```

Pay particular attention to `tint` multiplier – you must use `0.9999` value in case your texture has transparent parts.

And [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75340244/realitykit-how-to-make-an-entity-and-its-pbr-materials-transparent/75340920#75340920) you can find how to setup transparency of PhysicallyBasedMaterial.

#### `RealityKit` (visionOS)

In RealityKit for visionOS, there's the `OpacityComponent` with a default `opacity` parameter = 1.0.

```
let model = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.1), 
                   materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .red, 
                                         isMetallic: true)])

model.components[OpacityComponent.self] = .init(opacity: 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you found a way to animate fading? Seems you can create the animation in RealityComposer, but only completely show or completely hide.

Comment: You should do it in RealityKit, not in Reality Composer.

Comment: I agree, but since it's in RealityComposer there has to be a way to do it programatically, which I can't find haha. An Entity conforms to HasTransform, but that will only allow you to animate scale, position, and orientation. Nothing to do with animation of the material for something like fading it in or out.

Comment: @ColdLogic, please create a new question and publish a link here – I'll try to answer it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59765252/realitykit-animate-opacity-of-a-modelentity

Comment: this literally doesn't work at all if you use a simplematerial without a texture when running on iOS in arkit. The material is metallic with no opacity at all

Comment: https://twitter.com/MaxxFrazer/status/1364947082981818374?s=20 opacity doesn't work if you are updating the mesh size after the initial creation of the model entity. This is yet another realitykit bug, and the reason i thought your solution didnt work :) fixed the vote for you

Comment: Hi @zackify, if you wanna discuss any question, please post it here, I don't like twitter))

Comment: Hi, i have been using an image and used as a texture, but i only want to use the image as texture not any color. how can i do i?. tintcolor .clear does clears the mesh

Comment: Hi @elk_cloner, publish it as a question, I'll answer it.

Comment: @AndyJazz, could you please check this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70321744/how-to-show-image-from-gallery-in-realitykit

Comment: @AndyJazz About the "weird reflection left from sphere" bug. I have used SimpleMaterial with UIColor.clear & UIColor.clear.withAlphaComponent(0.0) to get a transparent ModelEntity horizontal plane. It is never fully transparent, there is always this "white-like" plane color. When I use the UnlitMaterial then its a "black-like" plane color. This seems to be a bug. Do you know any workarounds (or should I post another q)?

Comment: Please post a new question, I'll answer it tomorrow. ))

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code if you want full transparency for your ModelEntity:

```
    let invisibleMaterial = UnlitMaterial(color: .clear)
    let tapEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: replaceThisWithYourMesh, materials: [invisibleMaterial])
```

**Explanation:**

Initially, I was using SimpleMaterial, and no solution was making the entity completely invisible. So I looked at the documentation and it turns out there is another Material called UnlitMaterial that was perfect for my use case:

> UnlitMaterial:
> A simple material that doesn’t respond to lights in the scene.

Alternatively, you can also use the OcclusionMaterial which also hides the object behind the entity.

Answer (score -2):

I've found a several ways to do that.

1. **Without animation** and the easiest is to use `OcclusionMaterial()`:

```
let plane = ModelEntity(
                       mesh: .generatePlane(width: 0.1, depth: 0.1), 
                       materials: [OcculusionMaterial()]
            )
```

change existing Entity's opacity:

```
plane.model?.materials = [OcclusionMaterial()]
```

2. **With animation** (you can tweak these snippets for your needs):

```
var planeColor = UIColor.blue

func fadeOut() {
        runTimer(duration: 0.25) { (percentage) in
            let color = self.planeColor.withAlphaComponent(1 - percentage)
            var material: Material = SimpleMaterial(color: color, isMetallic: false)
            if percentage >= 0.9 {
                material = OcclusionMaterial()
            }
            self.plane.model?.materials = [material]
        }

}

func fadeIn() {
        runTimer(duration: 0.25) { (percentage) in
            let color = self.planeColor.withAlphaComponent(percentage)
            let material: Material = SimpleMaterial(color: color, isMetallic: false)

            self.plane.model?.materials = [material]
        }
}

func runTimer(duration: Double, completion: @escaping (_ percentage: CGFloat) -> Void) {
        let startTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        let endTime = duration + startTime

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1 / 60, repeats: true) { (timer) in
            let now = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

            if now > endTime {
                timer.invalidate()
                return
            }
            let percentage = CGFloat((now - startTime) / duration)
            completion(percentage)

        }
}
```

hope this helped someone )