# Apply a custom texture to Plane entity using RealityKit 2.0

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I i want to apply a custom text like a "grid" to a Plane Entity in RealityKit but I can't find the updated solution.
so far I have try this code:

```
func createBoard() {
    let planeMesh = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 1, 
                                              height: 1, 
                                        cornerRadius: 0.2)
    var myMaterial = SimpleMaterial()
    myMaterial.baseColor = try! .texture(.load(named: "texture.png")) 

    //'baseColor' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: use `color` property instead
    myMaterial.metallic = MaterialScalarParameter(floatLiteral: 0.5)
    myMaterial.roughness = MaterialScalarParameter(floatLiteral: 0.5)
    myMaterial.tintColor = UIColor.blue

    //'tintColor' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: use `color` property instead
    let modelEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: planeMesh, materials: [myMaterial])
}
```

But I'm getting the warning that base color and tintcolor are deprecated on iOS 15, I can't find the way to correct this issue.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement brand-new parameters instead of deprecated arguments:

```
func createBoard() {
    
    let planeMesh = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 1,
                                              height: 1,
                                        cornerRadius: 0.05)
    
    var material = SimpleMaterial()
    
    material.color = try! .init(tint: .white,
                             texture: .init(.load(named: "img", in: nil)))
    material.metallic = .init(floatLiteral: 1.0)
    material.roughness = .init(floatLiteral: 0.5)

    let modelEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: planeMesh,
                             materials: [material])
    
    let anchor = AnchorEntity()
    anchor.addChild(modelEntity)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
}
```

Also, you can use the following syntax:

```
var material = SimpleMaterial()
material.color.texture = .init(try! .load(named: "img", in: nil))
```

If you need mode details, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084240/realitykit-how-to-set-a-modelentitys-transparency/59117633#59117633).