# Adding real-world lighting to RealityKit's VideoMaterial

Tags: swift, realitykit

I am using VideoMaterial material on plane, in RealityKit to play video over an object in AR. This works easily, but I would like the video to change brightness based on the real world lighting. I thought this is done automatically, but with the VideoMaterial it doesn't work.

Can you please advice me whether it's possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RealityKit's [VideoMaterial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/videomaterial) does not respond to lighting. VideoMaterials are basically [UnlitMaterials](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/unlitmaterial), which means that scene lighting doesn’t affect them.

In SceneKit, in exactly the same way, `LightingModel.constant` does not react to light.

P. S.

Add an extra semi-transparent top plane with SimpleMaterial to [integrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084240/realitykit-how-to-set-a-modelentitys-transparency/59117633#59117633) a video into environment.

Comment: I thought this would be the case, but is there perhaps any workaround to this how I could make the video look more blended into the environment despite this?

Comment: Use a semi-transparent plane with SimpleMaterial over a plane with VideoMaterial, that will catch highlights from light sources.